# How to change build configuration in Xcode Cloud pipeline?

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

- For CI/CD we are using Xcode Cloud.
- My application have three build configurations: **Debug**, **Stage** and **Release**.
- In the **Xcode Cloud** we have set up two pipelines: **Stage** and **Release**.
- Default build configuration for archive state is **Release**. Image attached

When we are triggering **Stage** pipeline it executes archive with **Release** configuration. Here is no the way to set build configuration for pipeline.

**How to change active build configuration in Xcode Cloud pipeline?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am also trying to find out how to do this without creating a separate Scheme - you can select the Scheme from Xcode Cloud configuration.

Comment: @BenThomas I have reported this issue in the Apple's system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to create another scheme, like BSG-Stage and set the build configuration of it to Stage (instead of release).
Then you can add a separate workflow in XCode cloud for the staging and select the "BSG-Stage" scheme.

Answer (score 1):

XCode cloud allows you to have scripts running before doing the actual compilation.

In either `ci_post_clone.sh` or `ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh` it should be possible to do a simple modification of the scheme you are building to have a different default build config.

Something like this:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/buildConfiguration = ".*"/buildConfiguration = "'$CHOSEN_CONFIG'"/g' projectName.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/$CI_XCODE_SCHEME.xcscheme
```

`CHOSEN_CONFIG` can be set as an environment variable in the XCode cloud workflow, so you can just create one workflow per desired build config type.

Note: this is hackish, prone to be broken at any time. You could parse the xml scheme file and modify the specific `buildConfiguration` you need, but even that could be broken in the future. Hopefully Apple will expose an official way to change the config soon.